# Carga de datos MySql con php y ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Primero lo que tengo hecho:
Por web subo un **archivo.csv** al servidor y luego lo subo a una tabla `mysql`.

Lo que necesito:
Una ves los datos ya estan en tabla, procesarlos.

Como la data es mucha a veces mi idea es lo siguiente (que no me funcionó y por ahora lo que se ejecuta se realiza con formularios y metodos de envio POST y página queda en blanco hasta que termina el proceso, la pestaña del navegador no muestra imagen de carga o algo parecido, por lo que pareciera que no se ejecuta nada, pero si monitoreo los proceso `mysql`, los datos se están procesando con un `SP() MySql`):

1. Link o botón.
2. Al hacer click en él, no me recargue la página, y llame por debajo con ajax a otro php que sólo ejecuta un procemiento almacenado que manipula y procesa los datos.
3. Una vez se haya hecho click, mientras se ejecuta lo de arriba(2), mostrar una imagen gif de carga o un mensaje que los datos se estan procesando(para que pagina no este en blanco 5 o más minutos).
4. Cuando finalice el procesamiento de los datos, cambiar el mensaje o imagen del procesamiento por "Carga realizada" o despliegue de errores.

El código fuente es:

```
<?
session_start();
require "comun.inc";
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
set_time_limit(0);


$objetoWeb= new WEBPanel();
$objetoWeb->cabeceraTemplate();//cabecera template
$objetoWeb->tituloModulo('DATOS NUEVOS');//Titulo del modulo
//$objetoWeb->moduloFiltro($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$menu = new menuLite( $objDb, $_SESSION["NIVEL_DE_ACCESO"], "skin-web.css" );
$menu->creaMenu();
$objStyle = new styleDatos();
$rutaCalendar = "../../clases/web/calendario_web/";
echo "<BR><BR>";

$conexion = conectar_bd();
$error="";

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos1.css" type="text/css">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="overlib.js"></script>
        <DIV ID="overDiv" STYLE="position:absolute; visibility:hide;z-index:1;"></DIV>
    </head>
<body>
    <br>
    <font size="2"><b>El archivo debe estar en formato .csv(texto plano) separado por ";" y este es el formato que debe contener:</b></font><br/>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/tablacert.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br><br>
                <b style='color:#0000ff;'>
                    <?=utf8_decode("- El orden de las columnas es importante(debe ser el mismo), la subida del archivo omite en la carga, la 1° línea correspondiente a los titulos de columnas, los cuales deben estar en el archivo.")?>
                </b><br><br>
                <b>
                    - Fechas en formato YYYYmmdd.<br><br>
                    - Numeros enteros sin puntos ni coma.<br><br>
                    - Fecha de castigo indicada en YYYYmmdd.<br><br>
                    - Si el archivo original es un excel que se pasa a .csv, antes de hacerlo se debe reemplazar en toda la data ";" por nada o por un espacio " ".
                </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <form name="frm" action="sube_certificados.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr class="td">
                <td>
                    <div><b>Carga de Certificados de Acsa:</b></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br><br>
        <input type='hidden' name='flag' value='Enviado'>
        <input name="file" type="file" />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" />
    </form>
</body>

<?
if(isset($_POST['flag']))
{

    $varArNombre= (isset($HTTP_POST_FILES['file'])?$HTTP_POST_FILES['file']['name']:'');
    $varArContenido= (isset($HTTP_POST_FILES['file'])?$HTTP_POST_FILES['file']['tmp_name']:'');
    if($varArNombre!=''){
        if(!move_uploaded_file($varArContenido,"archivos/".$varArNombre)) echo "error al subir el archivo";
    }


    #validación del archivo
    $archivo = "archivos/".$varArNombre;
    $fp = fopen($archivo,'r');
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $cont = 0;
    $retorno_error="";
    $error='NO';

    #leemos el archivo
    $i=1;

    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE webcertificadosdb.CERTIFICADOS_TBl;");

    while ($linea= fgets($fp,1024)){
        if($i>1)
        {
            $arrCampos = explode(';',$linea);

            $ic          = $arrCampos[0]*1;
            $folio       = $arrCampos[1]*1;
            $nsap        = $arrCampos[2]*1;
            $n_doc       = trim($arrCampos[3]);
            $emision     = $arrCampos[4]*1;
            $vencimiento = $arrCampos[5]*1;
            $valor_doc   = $arrCampos[6]*1;
            $rut         = trim($arrCampos[7]);
            $razon       = trim($arrCampos[8]);
            $causal      = trim($arrCampos[9]);
            $motivo      = $arrCampos[10]*1;
            $fech_cast   = $arrCampos[11]*1;

            $sqli = "
                INSERT INTO webcertificadosdb.CERTIFICADOS_TBl
                SELECT
                '$rut',
                '$ic',
                '$nsap',
                '$valor_doc',
                '$vencimiento',
                '$n_doc',
                '$motivo',
                '$causal',
                '$folio',
                DATE_FORMAT('$fech_cast','%Y-%m-%d'),
                '$razon',
                '$emision';   ";
            mysql_query($sqli)or die("Error al insertar datos a tabla de certificados : CERTIFICADOS_TBl.\n".mysql_error()."\n".$sqli);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($fp);    
    echo "<br><b>Se subieron : ".( $i >= 3 ? ($i-2): 0 )." registros.</b><br/>";

    if( $i >= 3 )
    {
    echo "
    <form name='frmSp' action='sube_certificados.php' method='POST'>
        <input class='button' type='submit' name='Procesar' value='Procesar Carga' />
    </form>";
    }


    if (file_exists($archivo)) unlink($archivo);
} // fin del if

if(isset($_POST['Procesar']))
{   
    echo"<div id='imgcarga'> </div>";
    ?>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("imgcarga").innerHTML = "<img src='img/loading.gif'  async='async'>";
    </script>
    <?php

    mysql_query("CALL webcertificadosdb.CargaTotalCertificados();") or die("Se produjo un error durante el procesamiento de los datos subidos");

    ?>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("imgcarga").innerHTML = " ";
    </script>
    <?php

    echo "<br><br><b>Certificados procesados</b>";
}


$objetoWeb->pieTemplate();
$objStyle->iFrameCalendar($rutaCalendar);
desconectar_bd();
?>
</html>
```

Comment: De prefrencia que puedas poner el codigo que tienes ya para que se entienda mejor la pregunta